# Object dealloc only crashes in iOS 4.3

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, crash, pushviewcontroller

I'm trying to figure out why pushing a viewController in my tableView using didSelectRowAtIndexPath would cause a crash in iOS 4.3, but in iOS 5.0+, it works fine.

It crashes right when I call:

```
self.customViewController = [[[CustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomViewController"bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

anytime after the first time the customViewController has been pushed.

Here's my relevant code:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) CustomViewController *customViewController;

-(void) dealloc // Dealloc of tableView.
{

[customViewController release];
customViewController = nil;

}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

self.customViewController = [[[CustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomViewController"bundle:nil] autorelease]; // Release old, allocate new, set it.

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:customViewController animated:YES];
[customViewController release]; // Balance out pushViewController's retain.


}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
self.customViewController = [[[CustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomViewController"bundle:nil] autorelease];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:customViewController animated:YES];
[customViewController release]; // Balance out pushViewController's retain. ---->NO
}
```

The last `release` is an extra one that is not needed.
You already have done an `autorelease` on it to have it's `retain count` down by one.

---

We will analyse this line

```
self.customViewController = [[[CustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomViewController"bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

you create a `CustomViewController` retain count == 1.
You say `autorelease` on it so retain count will be 0 later (probably the end of the run loop), but for now it's still 1 that is why you still have access to it, but treat it as 0.
After that you say `self.customViewController`, that property is retain, so retain count == 1.
And you are taking care of that 1 in your dealloc.
As of your comment :

> // Balance out pushViewController's retain.

You don't `Balance` those, you balance only the one `YOU own`. If the system make retain on your objects, it will release them when the system don't need them anymore.

Comment: Wait seriously? I really thought that it retains the viewController, but I guess it just retains the view?

Comment: @JoeRaythein It does retain the view controller, but it also releases it. It takes ownership of it. You already relinquished ownership when you called autorelease.

Comment: But I think that `release`should not crash the app when the controller its being pushed, it should crash it on the `dealloc` method but not on the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: The way I worded that was weird, but you are correct, it crashes when we dealloc it. It actually sort of NSLogs an infinite loop of dealloc messages (I'm noting when the customViewControllers are dealloced for debugging), same as a crash though.

Comment: @JoeRaythein - I don't think you need to have that property to keep that UIViewController around in your code, the navigation controller will retain it and will release it when it don't need it anymore.  That is the normal way, but you may want to keep it around for some good reason to.

Comment: So I removed the release after pushViewController and now the customViewController and its subview hierarchy never get released... Is that because the release that takes care of the retain property that's only in the dealloc method currently needs to be called every time that we allocate a new view controller? Or would that probably mean there's a more deep-rooted memory management issue at work within CustomViewController?

Comment: @JoeRaythein The way your code is it will get release only if you select an other row, or when `Dealloc` of your `UITableViewController` sub class (I presume) get deallocated, because it is retained by your property. I you want it to be release when it get `pop` out of the screen, don't store in a property. Read my previous comment for that.

Answer (score 1):

Don't release the customViewController. You've already autoreleased it when you assigned it, so you've already given up ownership from the `alloc`. You don't have to release or autorelease the object again. The navigation controller takes ownership and will relinquish it by itself at the appropriate time.

Also, it's coincidence that you may see it in one version and not another. This is a memory management problem, so any corruption you might see (crashes, etc.) will be dependent on the state of memory on the device whenever you run the app. You may see a crash all the time, never, or only after running Skype but before opening the Photos app.

A good way to look for these is to enable zombies during your debugging sessions. With zombies enabled, objects are never actually released. Instead they are put into a zombie state and if they're ever sent a message again, they will abort the app and show you where the stray message was sent to help you debug your memory issues.